# Combine QUERY Function with Criteria to Skip N/A Not Working in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm so close to getting this formula to work, but I'm really stuck here. I'm using the following formula:

```
=IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, QUERY('Key1'!$A$3:$D$34, "select A where D=" & MIN('Key1'!$D$2:$D$34)))), "")
```

Basically, it's pulling the value in column A based on the lowest score in column D. For example, if I had:

| Place | Event | Quarter | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Random 1 | Online | 1 | 25% |
| Random 2 | Online | 2 | 100% |
| Random 3 | Online | 3 | 0% |

The formula would return "Random 3".

That being said, I have some "N/A" values in column D. As a result, when there are more "N/A" values than scores, the formula doesn't work, because there are more text columns than numeric (I think).

How can I get the formula to ignore values that are "N/A"?

Also for some reason, the formula keeps returning a value in column A that is not associated with the lowest score in column D.

I have the following:

| Place | Event | Quarter | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | Online | 1 | 87% |

And the formula will return "x" as having the lowest score, no matter what value is there. This is only happening with this row.

Answer (score 0):

jump to FILTER:

```
=IFNA(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, FILTER(Key1!A3:A34, Key1!D3:D34=MIN(Key1!D3:D34))))
```

Comment: This is awesome. One thing is that it's returning all values in A when the values in D haven't been filled out yet. How can I get it to ignore blanks? Adding <>"" didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @user19080962 can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?